# Url Encoding in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I have an url with spaces:

> http://mihalko.eu/image/data/ister/Nomad Plus-G- cierno cervena.jpg

(browser can open this link)
What is the best way to urlencode this url (space=%20)?

> Nomad%20Plus-G-%20cierno%20cervena.jpg

urlencode:

> http%3A%2F%2Fmihalko.eu%2Fimage%2Fdata%2Fister%2FNomad+Plus-G-+cierno+cervena.jpg

(browser can't open this link)
urlencode give me this result, but my browser wont't open this url.

Comment: That's URL encoding, not HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode):

```
echo rawurlencode('Nomad Plus-G- cierno cervena.jpg');
// Nomad%20Plus-G-%20cierno%20cervena.jpg
```

If you're okay with spaces being encoded as `+` then just use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) instead.

Comment: I edited my question, but the result is same with rawurlencode. But why?

Comment: @Adrian You shouldn't encode the whole url, only the components that need encoding individually. You don't want to encode all the `/`s in your url, but if you wanted a `/` in a component you would encode it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have some directories with space in their names, and this trick doesn't work. Please check my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the last "/" and use urlencode for last part of your string, like that:

```
$pos=strrpos($url,"/")+1;
$newurl=substr($url,0,$pos) . rawurlencode(substr($url,$pos));
```

If your only problems are spaces, then you could use

```
str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works until I have space in the directory name: http://d.pr/n/uRFH+ (code with comment)

Answer (score 0):

str_replace('%2F','/',rawurlencode('url')); This is working.